# I want to use the Same View to show different result in different nav bar using MVC razor Engine.I have designed a page using html tags

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have designed a page using html tags. i have used the same code in a View in my MVC application. The page has three tabs tab1, tab2 and tab3.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ViewName", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
 <div class="col">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" id="tab">Search</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link tab" id="tab2"  href="#tab2"</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link tab" id="tab3">Details</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
 <div class="col-auto text-right">
         @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Name) <!--This is my text box to enter the text.-->

          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search" name="Search" action="ViewName"><!--On submitting it, it will hit the "test" action method in the Controller.-->

        </div>


 <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="results-tab">
            <table id="Table" class="table" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Name1</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>name2</td>
                        <td>name2</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="details" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="details-tab">Details</div>-- the above is the table to which i want to bind the data and show the result and it is in the same view.
}
```

The above is the HTML code i am using in my view of the MVC code. i have three tabs in my Html code.
In my Tab1:
I have a text box with my search button.
I am binding the text box to the required model property.
After i have entered the text and hit the search button. It would call an API and give the list which contains or equals the required text.In my controller i have used the [HttpPost] attribute.I am posting the form on clicking the submit button.

```
public IActionResult ViewName()
        {
            NameModel obj = new NameModel();
            return View("ViewName", obj);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult ViewName(NameModel obj1)
        {
            NameModel model = new NameModel();
            -- Call the api and take out the Json response.
            --Bind the json response to the Model.
            --Send the model back to the same view but different tab.

            return View("ViewName", model);

        }
```

Now i want to display the result in the Tab2 in the grid format which is in the Same View.

The tab2 contains the table. How do i bind the resulted model value to it since it is in the same view.

I dont want to use the JQuery. i want to use any .net core concepts to implement it.
Can someone please tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution 1: Partial view included in different views

I would go for another type of implementation. It looks like the views are indeed different from each other and the fact that you require different models for each tab tells me the same.

If that's the case, [Check the partial view guide here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/partial-view-in-asp.net-mvc)

The main idea is to create the navbar as a reusable partial view, and include it in every other View (that is every other tab) you want to use.

#### Solution 2: Use the jquery option

MVC uses html/css and javascript to render clientside items. It is not non-MVC practice to use JQuery with it, it is in fact a common practice.

#### Solution 3: Use razor logic [check w3schools entry](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/razor_cs_logic.asp)

You can add checks like this below in your razor and have one model

```
@if (Model.Tab == 1)
{
 <div class="col-auto text-right">
         @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Name) <!--This is my text box to enter the text.-->

          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search" name="Search" 
    action="ViewName"><!--On submitting it, it will hit the "test" action method in the 
    Controller.-->
}
        </div>
```

Now in your backend, change the `Model.Tab` and have an overall model like this:

```
public MyModel {
   public int Tab;
   public TabOneModel;
   public TabTwoModel;
   public TabThreeModel;
}
```

While I have seen this quite a lot it has major disadvantages.

1. You can't apply an overall validation.
2. Your code will become very complicated in a single function. It violates multiple principles and can't be easiy unit tested.

Comment: Hi Athanasios, I am using RenderPartialAsync to render the Grid. But after using, it is throwing error "The page is not working".It doesn't load the page. How do i render the main view even after using RenderPartialAsync and without binding any data to it.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you could post the name using ajax and return the partial view where locates the Tab2 content, and display the result to the main view.

Refer to my following steps:

1.ViewName.cshtml

```
@model NameModel
<div class="col">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Search</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link tab" href="#tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Grid</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link tab" href="#tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Details</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab">
        <div class="col-auto text-right">
            <input asp-for="@Model.Name" id="myText" />

            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="myFunction()" value="Search" id="Search" name="Search" /><!--On submitting it, it will hit the "test" action method in the Controller.-->

        </div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2">
        <div id="Tab2Content">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3">ccc</div>
</div>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var name = document.getElementById("myText").value;

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Home/ViewName',

                data: { name: name },
                error: function (result) {
                    console.log("error");
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#Tab2Content").html(result);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

2.Post method:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ViewName(NameModel obj1)
    {
        NameModel model = new NameModel();
        -- Call the api and take out the Json response.
        --Bind the json response to the Model.
        --Send the model back to the same view but different tab.

        return PartialView("_Tab2PartialView", tab2model);

    }
```

3.Partial View (located at `/Views/Shared/_Tab2PartialView.cshtml`) to display the grid

```
@model tab2model
@*or @model List<tab2model>*@
@*grid view*@
<table id="Table" class="table" style="width:100%">
       <thead>
           <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Name1</th>
           </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>name2</td>
                    <td>name2</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Hi Xing, I am trying to use RenderPartialAsync  to load my Partial View.After using it, the page is not loading. It is error "The page is not working". How do i render the page without binding it to any data and i am using RenderPartialAsync to render the partial View

Comment: @Pooja Sharma Do not understand the problem without codes.Maybe refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-3.1#asynchronous-html-helper) But this way could not help you  show it in the same view after  submiting the form.My soultion is using js to render the partial view.